# How to avoid hardcoding Visualforce Page names in PageReferences?

Tags: apex, visualforce, commandbutton

I have a button which takes the user to a new page and passes through an Id parameter. I eventually want to package these into an app, which will mean there will be a namespace. How do I do this easily? I have the following code now, which I think will fail once packaged?

```
public PageReference myPageLink(){ 
    return new PageReference('/apex/MyPageAboutCases?Id='+caseId);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
PageReference myPage = Page.MyPageAboutCases;
myPage.getParameters().put('id', caseId);
```

Check out this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_system_pagereference.htm

And this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_System_PageReference_methods.htm

Answer (score 6):

I think you should use an explicit reference so it doesn't break while packaging:

```
PageReference p = Page.TheVisualforcePage;
p.getParameters().put('id', caseId);
```

Daniel Ballinger has an excellent post on this: [Safe URLs for custom buttons and page references](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/12/safe-urls-for-use-with-salesforce.html)